# How to create a flowable transaction in Room which is having different Object types?

Tags: android, transactions, rx-java, rx-java2, android-room

I want to implement search for my application therefor I want to query two tables in the same time based on their name and want to return the result when ever it founds a related name is there in the same table so what I had done is I created a Dao and Wrote the following code

```
    @Dao
        abstract class SearchDao {


            @Query("SELECT * FROM CHANNELS WHERE name LIKE :name")
            abstract Flowable<List<Channel>> getAllChannels(String name);

            @Query("SELECT * FROM MOVIES channels WHERE name LIKE :name")
            abstract Flowable<List<Movie>> getAllMovies(String name);

   }
```

So what I thought is of creating a transaction so that it will do all the work But I'm stuck here on how to create a transaction Please help me in this.

Comment: you can't make a join between your tables and avoid calling two requests ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out same you can do with getAllMovies().

```
roomDb.yourDao().getAllChannels(name)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(new Consumer<List<Channel>>() {
   @Override
   public void accept(List<Channel> channel) {
        // showAllChannels(channel) 
}

});
```

Comment: I wanted to create a transaction this is the general way to call the db instead of two separate calls I need to make it as a transaction so that both the query gets executed in the same time and remove the bloatware code